# Sencha Touch 2: 3 containers: stick to the left (fixed width) + stick to the right (fixed width) +middle (the rest)

Tags: css, extjs, css-float, sencha-touch-2

What's the best way to align three containers horizontally of the width of 3em for the left container and 3em for the right container and the rest width for the middle one?

```
layout:{
    type : 'hbox',
    pack : 'center'
},

items:[
{/*3em*/
xtype:'container',
cls:'left',
html:'left text',
},
{
xtype:'container',
cls:'middle',
html:'middle text',
},
{/*3em*/
xtype:'container',
cls:'right',
html:'right text',
},
]
```

I'm curious if I'd better use pure css `float:left;`, `float:right;` and `overflow:hidden;`, or it is possible to use `flex` for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you set a fixed width on both your side containers, you can set `flex: 1` on your center container. But you already seem there, I don't see what's blocking you?

Edit:

Touch accepts 'em' as width option for container (where Ext4 doesn't), so I would really avoid CSS for positioning of child items (or drop the container entirely, since that would render it helpless).

From my test, updating your code this way will do the trick:

```
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
        ,pack: 'center'
    }

    ,defaultType: 'container'

    ,items: [{
        html: 'Left'
        ,width: '3em'
        ,style: 'background: pink;' // just to materialize the container
    },{
        html: 'Center'
        ,flex: 1
    },{
        html: 'Right'
        ,width: '3em'
        ,style: 'background: pink;'
    }]
```

Comment: I'm asking about the most correct way. In my case, with pure css, I have to add an additional class to use overflow:hidden. I'm curious if Sencha Touch allows to make it in its own (and a proper) way. That's why I'm asking. :)

Comment: And that's really important for you to set your width in em instead of px?

Comment: That's the requirement from above:)